# MVC 3 to MVC 5 project issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I do not use on a daily basis MVC and I have a strange error.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ytworkspace_sharesOption_enum'.
```

Invalid column name 'ytworkspace_optimisationObjective_enum'.

except that

```
Public Enum_ShareTypes.Enums ytworkspace_sharesOption_enum 
{
get {return Enum_ShareTypes.getEnum (ytworkspace_sharesOption); }
set {this.ytworkspace_sharesOption = Enum_ShareTypes.getNumber (value); }
}

Public Enum_OptimisationObjective.EnumO ytworkspace_optimisationObjective_enum       
{
get {return Enum_OptimisationObjective.getEnum (ytworkspace_optimisationObjective); }
set {this.ytworkspace_optimisationObjective = Enum_OptimisationObjective.getNumber (value); }
}
```

Previously, it was the MVC version 3.0.0 and it worked but after moving the new version 5.0.0 MVC stopped working.
I had to change the variable names because they clung to Enum types.
Thanks for the help

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question.

> I had to change the variable names because they clung to Enum types.

That's your problem. You didn't migrate or otherwise update your database after this change, so when it attempts to access the column name it expects based on the *current* property name, it fails because no such column exists.

Comment: the only thing that changed it
enum ShareTypes.Enum
on
enum ShareTypes.Enums
enum OptimisationObjective.Enum
on
Enum_OptimisationObjective.EnumO
ytworkspace_sharesOption_enum these columns has never been in the database
was only
ytworkspace_sharesOption on the basis of which is determined ytworkspace_sharesOption_enum

Comment: I can't understand your comment at all. However, the exception you're getting pretty clearly proves it *is* in the database. Perhaps you didn't expect it or want it to be, but that's besides the point.

Comment: hmm maybe so
ytworkspace_sharesOption_enum and
ytworkspace_optimisationObjective_enum
They never existed in the database even before the change
These are the old variable changed only the name of their type

Comment: Perhaps, it's now expecting them to be there for some reason. If you were to run a migration, you would most likely see EF try to create them. If you don't want them included in the database, they should be decorated with `[NotMapped]`.